# Отличие RTTI от динамического связывания

Tags: java

RTTI в java - это  не то же самое, что динамическое связывание (т.е полиморфизм), так?
В чем отличие RTTI (динамического определения типов) и динамического связывания?

Answer (score 2):

Динамическое (или позднее) связывание означает определение (связывание) метода во время его выполнения. Метод в свою очередь выбирается по его типу, то есть с применением RTTI (runtime type identification). То есть получается, что динамическое связывание использует RTTI.

В общем смысле RTTI шире динамического связывания, поскольку с помощью RTTI реализуется не только динамическое связывание, но также например и механизм рефлексий - [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)